# How can I get started with FaceTime on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id, facetime

I just bought a Retina Macbook pro about a week ago and I have been trying to use facetime.  When I go to select a contact, it dials them but stays in the connection position.  It just doesn't seem to make the facetime call.

I checked system preferences and I have noticed that Facetime isn't listed.  Shouldn't it be listed there since this is brand new?  How do i get it on my system preferences?  Do I need to turn it on?   I do have an Ipad that I do use and it works just fine.  I've even tried going to iCloud on the Mac and I don't see Facetime there either.

Is there a way to get this up and running?

Comment: You won't find FaceTime in System Prefs. Have you tried recording a video in Photo Booth? Perhaps there's a problem with the hardware?

Answer (score 2):

FaceTime is stored in /Applications/Facetime.app and all the settings and preferences you need are available from within the application's preferences and help menu.

Here is a nice troubleshooting article that might help.

- http://www.apple.com/support/mac/facetime/

Also, since you have a new mac, you should have 90 days of paid support to get you up and running. That support is really helpful for getting oriented since it's hard to expect a new user to know where to look for details on new hardware and potentially new software.

Comment: ..and the support people are very helpful in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The FaceTime app is in the Applications folder. In order to use it, you need an Apple Id. Open the FaceTime app and go to application Preferences and login with your Apple ID. After validating your Apple ID, you would be able to use it.